# Displaying a listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

When I'm calling `_showAllTasks()` from the **Add** item it's not visible

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late final NotifyHelper notifyHelper;
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  final _taskController = Get.put(TaskController());

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    notifyHelper = NotifyHelper();
    notifyHelper.initializeNotification();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _showAllTasks();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add)),
      backgroundColor: context.theme.backgroundColor,
      appBar: _appBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          _addTaskBar(),
          _addDateBar(),
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          _generateTasks(),
          _showTasks(),
          // _showAllTasks()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
_generateTasks() {
    return Container(
        height: 50,
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _showAllTasks();
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: Colors.grey),
                  child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                    "All",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Center(child: Text("Empty"));
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: Colors.grey),
                  child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                    "Completed",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Text("Empty");
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: Colors.grey),
                  child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                    "ToDo",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

```
_showAllTasks() {
    return Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: _taskController.taskList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              Task task = _taskController.taskList[index];
              print("her iammmm3");
              return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                position: index,
                child: SlideAnimation(
                  child: FadeInAnimation(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            _showBottomSheet(context, task);
                          },
                          child: TaskTile(task),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

but if I'm calling it in the build method it is then visible can anyone help me!!!!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think the `Expanded` around the listview is unnecessary